# Silence is not adding on end of an audio file

Tags: ios, swift, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition, avurlasset

I'm working on a demo of how to add extra silence audio at the end of a given audio file.

here my audio file length is 29 sec. & I'm adding 11-sec silence.
so, final output audio length will be 40 sec.

Here is my function,

```
func addSilenceInAudio(inputFilePath:URL, silenceTime: Int, minimumAudioLength: Int, completionBlock:@escaping ((String?, Error?) -> Void)) {

        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: inputFilePath, options: nil)

        //get an original audio length

        let endAudioTime = CMTimeMake(value: Int64(silenceTime), timescale: 1)

        let composition = AVMutableComposition()

        let insertAt = CMTimeRange(start: CMTime.zero , end: endAudioTime)
        let assetTimeRange = CMTimeRange(start: CMTime.zero, end:asset.duration)

        //here i'm inserting range
        try! composition.insertTimeRange(assetTimeRange, of: asset, at: insertAt.end)

        let exportSessionNew = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A)
        exportSessionNew?.outputFileType = AVFileType.m4a
        let documentURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        let dateString = (Date().millisecondsSince1970) //added file name here
        let outputURL = documentURL.appendingPathComponent("\(dateString).m4a") //file name must be .m4a
        exportSessionNew?.outputURL = outputURL //output url

        exportSessionNew?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {
            () -> Void in
            print(exportSessionNew as Any)
            if exportSessionNew!.status == AVAssetExportSession.Status.completed  {
                // All is working fine!!
                print(exportSessionNew?.outputURL as Any) //get outputfile
                print("success")
                completionBlock("\(String(describing: exportSessionNew?.outputURL))", nil)
            } else {
                print("failed")
                completionBlock(nil, exportSessionNew?.error)
            }
        })
    }
```

above code is working fine & I'm getting my output audio with 40 sec.

but **the Problem is 11-sec silence is adding in starting of an audio file.**

**it should be at the end of an audio file.**

I'm doing something wrong here?

Comment: Have you solved this? I'm having the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

You basically only need to extend the length of the audio.

So...

```
let assetTimeRange = CMTimeRange(start: CMTime.zero, end:asset.duration)
```

change to something like

```
let newDuration = asset.duration + silenceTime
let assetTimeRange = CMTimeRange(start: CMTime.zero, end:newDuration)
```

Disclaimer: It's a while since I've done this

Comment: Thanks, @Scriptable for your reply.
I've already tried above logic 
but unfortunately above logic is not working, it still giving me same result.